# Number of inputs in undecidability proof of halting problem

Tags: halting-problem

So first, just to make sure that I understand the proof, here is the proof as I understand it:

Take a program $H(x,y)$, which determines whether $x(y)$ will halt or not halt: if $x(y)$ halts then $H$ returns true, and otherwise it returns false.
If $H$ exists, we can construct a new program $H'$ which has one input $x$, defined by $H'(x) = H(x,x)$.
Using $H'$ we create a final function $H^+$, which loops forever if $H'$ returns true, and halts otherwise.

With this information, we can feed $H^+$ into itself — $H^+(H^+)$.
If the inside halts, then the outside must loop, but due to the definition of $H'$, $H^+(H^+)$ is the same as $H^+(H^+,H^+)$. The outside is the same as the inside, and so must halt. This is a contradiction, so $H(x,y)$ cannot exist.

The thing I find confusing about this, is that it assumes that the interior $H^+$ is the same as the exterior $H^+$, whereas to me it seems that they would be different by virtue of one being the input to the other.

Another question is what is the input for the interior $H^+$? by un-nesting the $H^+$’s, and unrolling the definition of $H'$, we get $H^+(H^+,H^+)$, then $H^+(H^+(H^+))$, then $H^+(H^+(H^+(H^+)))$, and so on, so what is the first input? If there is no input then the question of whether $H^+(H^+)$ halts, that is, whether $H^+$ halts with input $H^+$, makes no sense for the same reason that the question what is the number answer to $x^2$ doesn't make sense – the function requires an input and if the input is just a function, you are asking if a function halts without knowing the input. An example of this is $H^+(x)$, where $x$ is

```
If input = 1 
    Halt 
Else 
    Loop
```

Will this program halt? The answer is obviously that it depends on the input, so why is it not the same with the function $H^+(H^+)$?

Comment: I did my best to make sense of your prose.

Comment: Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, Turing machines have no input specification per se. They have an "input convention" which allows us to interpret them as accepting inputs. However, this makes little difference for the argument, so below I will assume that Turing machines do have a specified number of inputs.

The starting assumption is that there is a two-input Turing machine $H(x,y)$ which return whether the one-input Turing machine encoded by $x$ halts on the input $y$. From it, we construct a one-input Turing machine $H'(x)$ which computes $H(x,x)$. Finally, we construct a one-input Turing machine $H^+(x)$ which computes $H'(x)$, enters an infinite loop if $H'$ returned true, and halts otherwise.

We then consider what happens whether $H^+$ halts when run on $\# H^+$, which is the encoding of $H^+$. There are two possibilities:

1. Suppose that $H^+$ halts when run on $\# H^+$. Then $H'(\#H^+) = H(\#H^+,\#H^+)=\text{True}$, and so $H^+$ enters an infinite loop when run on $\#H^+$, contradiction.
2. Suppose that $H^+$ does not halt when run on $\# H^+$. Then $H'(\#H^+) = H(\#H^+,\#H^+)=\text{False}$, and so $H^+$ halts when run on $\#H^+$, contradiction.

In both cases we reach a contradiction, and so we conclude that $H$ cannot exist.

Comment: Sorry, so are you saying that $#H+$ represents the code of H+? What does that mean exactly?

Comment: A Turing machine is an abstract concept. In order to present it as input, we first need to encode it somehow, as a string. I denote by $\#T$ the encoding of the Turing machine $T$.

Comment: Ok understood. So why when $H+$ when run on $\#H+$ do we get $H′(#H+)=H(#H+,#H+)=True$, surely it should be $H(#H+, #H+)=False$ as H+ does the opposite of H. I dont understand why when you have said that when you run $H+$ on $\#H+$ your line of reason holds true.

Comment: Suppose that $H^+$ halts on $\#H^+$. By assumption on $H$, this means that $H(\#H^+,\#H^+)$ should return True. By definition of $H'$, this means that $H'(\#H^+)$ returns true. By definition of $H^+$, this means that $H^+$ does not halt on $\#H^+$. We have reached a contradiction.

Comment: "$H^+$ does the opposite of $H$" — right, that's the point of the construction, and the reason that the proof works.

Comment: According to the specification of $H$, if $x$ halts on $y$, then $H(x,y)$ returns True. In this case, $x=y=\#H^+$.

Comment: Ok, thank you, i understand this bit now, but i am still confused as to the input to the $H+$s as we continue to un-nest - $H+^1$ halts on $H+^2$ so $H(#H+^1, #H+^2)$ is defined as true, but then $H(#H+^2, #H+^3)$ must be false, but it seems that $H+^1,2 and 3$ are all different things due to the order of them appearing, because $H+^3$ is the input for $H+^2$, they are no longer the same.

Comment: There is no un-nesting. The procedure $H^+$ runs $H'$ on $\#H^+$, which runs $H$ on $(\#H^+,\#H^+)$, and that's it. There is no further un-nesting.

Comment: Ok sorry, but the main point still is that when we have $H(#H+,#H+)$ we are essentially asking does $H+(#H+)$ halt, which is the same as does $H+(#H+,#H+)$ halt which is the same as $H+(#H+(#H+))$ which is the same as $H+(#H+(#H+,#H+))$ and so on to infinity, so surely to answer the question of H(H+,H+) we must first work out what the first input is, as if we get $H+(H+(H+... (x^2,3)))))) then the question makes more sense, and even then not much. It seems that the problem with H+(H+) is due to an infinity occuring as opposed to the function itself no?

Comment: No. The problem is that if we assume that $H$ exists, then we reach a contradiction.

Comment: You are assuming that $H$ operates in a specific way, which is an unfounded assumption. In fact, $H$ does not exist, and so in particular, does not work in the way which you assume.

Comment: take a new function a(x,y) if x(y) is a, a outputs b, else a ouputs a. now a'(x) = a(x,x). a'(a') leads to a paradox in the same way as H+(H+), if a'(a') is a then a'(a') = a'(b) and so a(a',a') = a(b) so a',a' =b - paradox. But we can construct a function a', the issue is in the fact that a'(a') = a'(a'(a'(a'))) etc.

Comment: The issue is that if you assume that $H$ exists, then you reach a contradiction. Do you understand the logic of the argument? Is there any step you disagree with? If you have an alternative proof, you can write it in full and we can take a look, but the proof I wrote in the answer definitely works, and there is no need to look for any further proof, given that you are trying to understand this particular proof.

Comment: I do understand the logic of the argument (i think) im only confused as to what happens when you play around with the proof a bit more - looking more into what happens when we look at what the question H+(H+) actually is and if it makes sense, because to me it seems that H+(H+) just leads to a infinite string of H+s which doesnt make sense based on the paramenters of H+ which we assume for the proof.

Comment: Hence the analogy for the new function a(x,y)

Comment: I'm afraid that your intuition is wrong. We don't assume anything on how $H$ operates. The only assumption is that $H(x,y)$ returns True iff the machine encoded by $x$ halts on input $y$. How $H$ accomplishes it is up to $H$.

Comment: With the assumption that H exists, and the definition of H’ and H+, we can easily come to a contradiction which shows H doesn’t exist. We can also do endless substitutions that get us nowhere. The one contradiction gives us the result that was claimed. Endless  substitutions give us nothing, they also take nothing away. So we can just ignore them.

Comment: @Mercury There is no "nesting" or "un-nesting". You have this function called H and does some kind of calculation to figure out the halting problem (doesn't matter what the calculation is, as long as it figures out the halting problem) and eventually returns either true or false.

Answer (score 0):

Let H (x, y) be a Turing machine that returns true if the Turing machine with encoding x halts on input y, and returns false if that machine doesn't halt on input y. If H (x, y) exists then the halting problem is solved. If H (x, y) doesn't exist then the halting problem cannot be solved.

H' (x) returns true if the Turing machine with encoding x halts on input x, and returns false if the machine doesn't halt on input x.

$H^+$ (x) loops forever if the Turing machine with encoding x halts on input x, and halts if the machine doesn't halt on input x.

Let #$H^+$ be the encoding of the Turing machine $H+$. We try what happens if we use #$H^+$ as the x in the previous part: $H^+$ (#$H^+$) loops forever if the Turing machine with encoding #$H^+$ halts on input #$H^+$, and halts if the machine doesn't halt on input #$H^+$.

In other words, $H^+$ (#$H^+$) loops forever if $H^+$ halts on input #$H^+$, and halts if $H^+$ loops forever on input #$H^+$. $H^+$ (#$H^+$) loops forever if $H^+$ (#$H^+$) halts, and $H^+$ (#$H^+$) halts if $H^+$ (#$H^+$) loops forever.

In the last line, we had one calculation which loops forever if it halts, and halts if it loops forever. That's not possible. Therefore H doesn't exist.